# Why can't I get this video to automatically start on page load on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this video as a background with Bootstrap that I would like to autoplay on page load. It works fine with desktop Chrome, but not so much for mobile.

It is a small, .mp4 file that is created using:

```
<video class="video-fluid" id="video1" autoplay loop>
    <source src="videos/light-swaying.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

The only thing that shows up on mobile is just a still of the first frame, not a moving video. I added this script at the bottom of my body, and it actually starts the video fine. It loops and everything:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var video = document.getElementById('video1');
    var aboveView = document.getElementById('video-carousel-example2');
    aboveView.addEventListener('click', function () {
        video.autoplay = true;
        video.play();
    }, false);
</script>
```

The only problem is, though, I have to click on the video to actually start it. I tried this script in the same spot, and no luck whatsoever:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var video1 = document.getElementById('video1');
    video1.autoplay = true;
    video1.play();
</script>
```

So does anyone have any idea how to fix this and make it play automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Chrome? Because:
"Autoplay was disabled in previous versions of Chrome on Android because it can be disruptive, data-hungry and many users don't like it."

Source:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay

Comment: Thank you so much, I just added the `muted` tag I read from the article and boom, it automatically played!

Answer (score 1):

Mostly we too find this issues in ipad and tablets because ipad and tablet doesnt support the autoplay

To see a full list of these restrictions, see the official docs: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

for that you need to trigger your click function by checking your monitor resolution i am not familiar with javascript so i am written this using jquery

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var screenWidth = $( window ).width();
       if(screenWidth <= 1024)//just i am checking for ipad only
      {
          $('#video-carousel-example2).trigger('click');
      }
     $('#video-carousel-example2).click(function(){
            var video1 = document.getElementById('video1');
            video1.play();
       })
    });
```